# Access MSSQL from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql

Am trying to connect to MSSQL database from Android Studio.

My code:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.66;databasename=POSEIDON;username=sa;password=myPass");
```

When making the query i receive:

```
 W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Single-Sign-On is only supported on Windows. Please specify a user name.
```

Comment: consider developing web services at back-end and on android side connecting these web services using http. It is the common way. Connecting to SqlServer from Android is not suggested. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492417/connect-to-sql-server-from-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: It is too much work for the current project. It's not a commercial app, it's only for internal use.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375437/java-sql-sqlexception-single-sign-on-is-only-supported-on-windows-please-speci

Comment: It mostly is, but i dont understand the answer.

Comment: I worked it out. This explains it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication .

Answer (score 0):

Access MSSQL database direct from Andriod it's not the right way  .  but something like an API (RESTFull , SOAP ) through which the records are queried and passed to the Android .

If you need to save date on database , **SQLite** is one way of storing app data .Its stores data to a text file on a device you don't need to establish any kind of connections for it like JDBC,ODBC e.t.c.

Below is tutorial on use SQLite:-

[Save Data using SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)

Comment: I actually am using MS SQL. I only read from the database, i don't store anything. Also, the project is not that big to develop a backend webservice. As you can see in the code i use the jdbc:jtds library.

Comment: Try to use the user/password  of Windows OS  that you run the database in instead of the usual SQL Server authentication .

Comment: I tried with my user, and i use both types of auth , integrated and Windows auth. It gives me the same error. I tried domain\\username.